# SQL Query from list of strings

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I am trying to query the last time a file was imported from a SQL table "import", given a month string integer (Jan is '01', Feb is '02', March is '03'..). I have pasted my solution below but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing so.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
months.month_string, MAX(import.process_date)
FROM import import,
(
    select '01' month_string from dual union
    select '02' month_string from dual union
    select '03' month_string from dual union
    select '04' month_string from dual union
    select '05' month_string from dual union
    select '06' month_string from dual union
    select '07' month_string from dual union
    select '08' month_string from dual union
    select '09' month_string from dual union
    select '10' month_string from dual union
    select '11' month_string from dual union
    select '12' month_string from dual 
) months
WHERE import.process_month (+) = months.month_string
GROUP BY months.month_string
ORDER BY months.month_string;
```

Comment: Is there ever anything other than '01' - '12' for the `month_string`?

Comment: There are no other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you will find this more "elegant", but here is a better way to write the query:

```
SELECT months.month_string, MAX(import.process_date)
FROM (select '01' as month_string from dual union all
      select '02' as month_string from dual union all
      select '03' as month_string from dual union all
      select '04' as month_string from dual union all
      select '05' as month_string from dual union all
      select '06' as month_string from dual union all
      select '07' as month_string from dual union all
      select '08' as month_string from dual union all
      select '09' as month_string from dual union all
      select '10' as month_string from dual union all
      select '11' as month_string from dual union all
      select '12' as month_string from dual 
     ) months LEFT OUTER JOIN
     import
     on import.process_month = months.month_string
GROUP BY months.month_string
ORDER BY months.month_string;
```

Here are the changes:

- Replaced the (uninterpretable) Oracle syntax for outer joins with an explicit, ANSI standard outer join.
- Reversed the order of the tables, to use a `left outer join` rather than a `right outer join`.
- Changed `select distinct` to `select`.  `select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.
- Changed `union` to `union all`.  `union` expends effort to remove duplicates, which is not needed.
- Added `as` for the column aliases.  This makes it more apparent that the name is being assigned to the column, and helps prevent wandering commas from messing up the query.

You could also use a `connect by` or recursive CTE to actually generate the month numbers, but I'm not sure that would be as clear as this version.

EDIT:

I was making the assumption that you need to get `NULL` values out because not all months would be present in `import`.  That is why you would use a `months` table.  If not, just do:

```
SELECT i.process_month, MAX(i.process_date)
FROM import i
GROUP BY i.process_month
ORDER BY i.process_month;
```

If you are concerned about the range,

```
SELECT i.process_month, MAX(i.process_date)
FROM import i
WHERE i.process_month in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
                          '11', '12'
                         )
GROUP BY i.process_month
ORDER BY i.process_month;
```

Comment: wouldn't be faster to do a sub-query that groups by import.process_month and takes the max and then join that result to the composed table?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of not using the depricated oracle syntax for joins.  I will have to research this "union all", I have only used union in the past.

Comment: @eniacAvenger - `UNION` checks to make sure there are no duplicates in the results, and can run very slowly because of this. `UNION ALL` doesn't check for duplicates and will often run much faster. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis sorry about the accepting/unaccepting of the answer, I am new to stackoverflow and thought that I could accept more than one answer.  I have selected this answer since it will solve the problem in all scenarios.

Comment: @eniacAvenger - I honestly hadn't noticed anything so no problem here. :-) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
WITH SUMMARY_DATA AS
  (SELECT CASE
            WHEN PROCESS_MONTH IN ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06',
                                   '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12')
              THEN PROCESS_MONTH
            ELSE
               NULL
          END AS SUMMARY_MONTH,
          PROCESS_DATE
     FROM IMPORT)
SELECT SUMMARY_MONTH, MAX(PROCESS_DATE)
  FROM SUMMARY_DATA
  GROUP BY SUMMARY_MONTH
  ORDER BY SUMMARY_MONTH
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23b0a/1)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Just tested this and it works great.  In the future if I had a large list of strings, could you use a PL/SQL statement uses an array in the "IN" parentheses?

Comment: This answer confuses me because it will not show a summary month if there is no data present for that month.  That is why a `months` table would be used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - NULL seems to work fine as a 'default' or 'dummy' value for SUMMARY_MONTH in the subquery factoring clause. Please see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23b0a/1). Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis . . .  The original query uses a left outer join, presumably to get a row for 12 months, even if data is not present.  The SQL Fiddle returns 3 rows, not 12.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - ah, now I see what you're driving at. Yes, you're correct, my answer doesn't do that. I'd delete the answer as it doesn't seem to satisfy the original requirements, but OP's comment above seems to indicate it's acceptable so I guess I'll let it stand. Thanks.

Comment: @eniacAvenger - unfortunately it's not possible to use a PL/SQL array in an IN clause, at least through Oracle v11. I haven't got a version 12 instance to play with - can anyone comment as to whether this has changed in the latest version of Oracle?  Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Fair enough, I guess at that point a cursor or varray would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use all_objects for counter, distinct is not neccessary in this query

```
select months.month_string, MAX(import.process_date)
from import import, 
     (select lpad(to_char(rownum), 2, 0) month_string from all_objects where rownum <= 12) months
where  import.process_month (+) = months.month_string
group by months.month_string
order by months.month_string
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also an interesting solution to the problem.  Just tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since there aren't any other values for the `process_month` you can accomplish this without the implicit `Join` to a months table.

Perhaps the following will work?

```
SELECT  process_month, MAX(process_date)
FROM    import
GROUP BY process_month
ORDER BY process_month;
```

Comment: There could be a month that does not have import data, and I need the results to show up as null if this happens.  Therefore I need to feed it a list of month strings.  But thanks for the suggestion.